# How to use transaction in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to use transaction with commit,rollback and try catch block in snowflake like sql server?

SQL Server:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        --Insert statement 1
        --Insert statement 2
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

As per the snowflake documentation we can use transaction like this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION NAME T1;
-- Insert statement 1;
-- Insert statement 2;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 4):

The TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR session parameter allows statements that return an error to abort a non-autocommit transaction. All statements issued inside that transaction fail until a commit or rollback statement is executed to close the transaction.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#transaction-abort-on-error

Answer (score 3):

As of today Snowflake does not provide an equivalent construct. We're working on a feature (to be released *very* soon) allowing aborting a transaction if any statement in it fails, which should address this use case.

Answer (score 2):

To Begin a transaction in the current session.

```
BEGIN [ WORK | TRANSACTION ] [ NAME <name> ]
START TRANSACTION [ NAME <name> ]
```

Example

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION NAME T1;

SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION();

-----------------------+
 CURRENT_TRANSACTION() |
-----------------------+
 1432071497832         |
-----------------------+

INSERT INTO A1 VALUES (1), (2);

-------------------------+
 number of rows inserted |
-------------------------+
 2                       |
-------------------------+

COMMIT;
```

Rollback

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A1;

----------+
 COUNT(*) |
----------+
 0        |
----------+

BEGIN NAME T4;

SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION();

-----------------------+
 CURRENT_TRANSACTION() |
-----------------------+
 1432071523422         |
-----------------------+

INSERT INTO A1 VALUES (1), (2);

-------------------------+
 number of rows inserted |
-------------------------+
 2                       |
-------------------------+

ROLLBACK;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A1;

----------+
 COUNT(*) |
----------+
 0        |
----------+
```

Comment: How you rollback the transaction if error is occurred in T1?